# what is the meaning of brackets after function : reverse[0]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reverse, zero, brackets

I'm using node v10.1 and i have an object which keeps some MIME types like this:

```
let all_mime_types = {
  //media types...

  text: "text/plain",
  html: "text/html",
  jpeg: "image/jpeg",
  jpg: "image/jpg",
  png: "image/png",
  javascript: "text/javascript",
  css: "text/css"
};
```

when i want to get to one of MIME types with some code(based on my refered files in directory), i see this code :

```
let mime =
        all_mime_types[
          path
            .extname(full_address)
            .split(".") // seperates the "." from path.extname(full_address);
            .reverse()[0]
        ];
```

my problem is `.reverse()[0]`part ...

when i delete 0 or [0] it returns undefined.

what does `.reverse()[]` and  `[0]` mean ?

Comment: `[0]` accessing first index of returned value of reverse method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `split(".")` takes string as an input, and returns array as output
2. reverse takes array and reverses it, as the name suggests
3. [0] is first element of the array, which in turn was last element of the original array

So, what this code does, is having string such as `"/path/to/file/some.txt"`, returns you `"txt"` as a result.

Let's rewrite this is less confusing style:

```
let file_path = path.extname(full_address)
let split_by_extension_path = file_path.split(".")
let reversed_path = split_by_extension_path.reverse()
let extension = reversed_path[0]
let mime = all_mime_types[extension]
```

Please note that there are multiple problems with this code.

First, not all files have extensions, and not all file extensions are correct.
Second, probably your JavaScript files have `.js` extension, and not `.javascript`. Same for `.text` and `.txt` files.

Comment: `.reverse()[0]` can be just `.pop()`